# unbind multiple classes except one

Tags: jquery

I have "n" different clasess

```
 .classOne
 .classTwo
 .classThree
 .classFour
   ....
 .classN
```

I want to bind `.classTwo` & unbind the rest except `.ClassOne`, How Should I do that?

```
   $("#container").off("click"); /*except classOne*/
  $("#container").on("click.ClassTwo",function...
```

**HTML**

```
     <DIV class="classOne">[Show alert]</div>
     <DIV class="classTwo">[Click dont show anything]</div>
     <DIV class="classThree">[Show alert]</div>
     <DIV class="classFour">[Show alert]</div>
     <DIV class="classFive">[Show alert]</div>
```

After clickin on this button, the click event deactivates for everyone excepts `classOne` ...(If you click it it stills shous an alert) and at the same time `.classTwo` gets the capacity to show an alert after clicking

```
         <DIV class="button">[]</div>
```

So, at the end the arrangement would be:

```
     <DIV class="classOne">[Show alert]</div>
     <DIV class="classTwo">[Show alert]</div>
     <DIV class="classThree">[Click dont show anything]</div>
     <DIV class="classFour">[Click dont show anything]</div>
     <DIV class="classFive">[Click dont show anything]</div>....
```

Comment: are they all the same type of element? Could we get some html to go with this?

Comment: Yes they are all  the same element, the code is pretty complex... the idea is depicted above.

Comment: can you please add HTML to have better understanding

Comment: Are those classes have similar name e.g. starts with 'myclass...'

Comment: @CumminUp07    updated. hope you can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are saying, they have a function bound to them already and then when you click on the button you want to unbind all and then rebind except for `.classTwo` which you can do like this:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('div').off('click');
    $('div').not('.classTwo').on('click', function() {
        // show alert
    })
})
```

Comment: What do you understand by writing this?  `$('div').not('.classTwo').not('.classFifty').off()` ? Do this turn off everything excepts `.classTwo` and `.classFifty`?

Comment: if you did `$('div').not('.classTwo').not('.classFifty').off('click')` that would unbind the click function from every div but classes `.classTwo` and `.classFifty`

Comment: terrific. this `.not()` method was what I was looking for. thank you!!

Comment: Glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

Add your classes to an array so they're more easy to manage, then join that array & use as your jQuery selector.

```
classList = ['One','Two','Three'...];

// remove 'One' from the classList if needed.
var index = classList.indexOf('One');
if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
classes = classList.join(' ');

// the jquery call, notice that we're using a string created by the .join() function called on our array of classes.
$('#container').on('click',classes,function(e){ /* ... */ }


// you can also loop one array and push it's items to a second one, might not be needed, but could help your work.
classes = [];
for(var thisClass in classList){
  classes.push('class'+classList[thisClass]);
}
```

further reading: [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)